# We need to do a selection sorter that can sort mixed variables list

Tags: python, selection-sort

I was creating a code that selection sorts but when i tried it, it say's that it can't compare str and int. I need help

```
def selection(collection):
for i in range(len(collection)):
    #assume that the first element is the smallest
    min_idx = i
    print(collection)
    for j in range(i+1, len(collection)):
         #compare if following elements are smaller
        if collection[min_idx] > collection[j]:
            min_idx = j #if yes, get index
    collection[i], collection[min_idx] = collection[min_idx], collection[i]
```

the list:

```
nlist = [19, 5, 'cat', 'rabbit', 2, 32, 'mice', 'dog', 7]
```

the output required:

```
[2, 5, 7, 19, 32, 'cat', 'dog', 'mice', 'rabbit']
```

error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: What is the ordering you want to obtain? All strings first, all strings last, something else?

Comment: Well, what is bigger - a `5` or a `'rabbit'`? And why?

Comment: Please see [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Meaning: give us all *relevant* code, and give us the exception stack trace. And well, get clear on your requirements. Ask yourself, when you were to compare the number 19 and the string "cat", how would you sort that? (hint: you can't. you can only sort lists entries that have the same type)

Comment: You cannot compare string with integer. Unless you define how to compare `5` with `'rabbit'`, this is impossible.

Comment: @alex Depends on the size of the rabbit, doesn't it. A small one might be less than 5, but a big hare, who knows, maybe 10?

Comment: Hint: implement exactly what you would do on paper. Python only support comparing two ints or two strings, given these how would you compare two objects of any type in your desired order?

Comment: if i try to put `if type(collection[i]) is int` what should i do next?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create two lists. One containing the integers and the other containing the strings. Sort each of them and then join them back together. You could do it like this:

```
nlist = [19, 5, 'cat', 'rabbit', 2, 32, 'mice', 'dog', 7]
dlist = [e for e in nlist if isinstance(e, int)]
clist = [e for e in nlist if not isinstance(e, int)]
answer = sorted(dlist) + sorted(clist)
print(answer)
```

You can try to use your own sort function rather than the built-in *sorted* function if you prefer

Comment: what if i want the output to have the steps of it arranging like: `['19', '5', 'cat', 'rabbit', '2', '32', 'mice', 'dog', '7']
['19', '5', 'cat', 'rabbit', '2', '32', 'mice', 'dog', '7']
['19', '2', 'cat', 'rabbit', '5', '32', 'mice', 'dog', '7']
['19', '2', '32', 'rabbit', '5', 'cat', 'mice', 'dog', '7']
['19', '2', '32', '5', 'rabbit', 'cat', 'mice', 'dog', '7']
['19', '2', '32', '5', '7', 'cat', 'mice', 'dog', 'rabbit']
['19', '2', '32', '5', '7', 'cat', 'mice', 'dog', 'rabbit']
['19', '2', '32', '5', '7', 'cat', 'dog', 'mice', 'rabbit']`

Comment: That's a different question. In your original question you had a mixture of strings and integers. Now they're all strings. I suggest you ask a new question as my answer provides **exactly** the output that you require in your original question.